# Scroll to last position if user does not scroll (RecyclerView) Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am consuming a ws when the user opens an activity the list is filled, after that, I call the ws each 5 seconds there I use

```
rv.scrollToPosition(sectionAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

to move automatically to last item. All of that is good but now If the user is scrolling the method makes to move to last item. How can I control that?
I want to do that like WhatsApp when user scroll to read old messages appears a button and if there is a new message the scroll does not move.

This is my code:

```
Thread thread;
Boolean fin_thread;
Boolean scroll_usuario = true;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ws();
    control_scroll();
}

private void ws() {
    //all process to set up the list
    ws_timer();
}

private void ws_timer() {
    fin_thread = true;
    thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (fin_thread){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            DataInfo data_info = new DataInfo();
                            data_info.setTitle("a");
                            data_info.setName("b");
                            obj.add(data_info);
                            sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            last_item(scroll_usuario);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

private void last_item(Boolean scroll_usuario) {
    if(scroll_usuario){
        rv.scrollToPosition(sectionAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }else{
        Log.d("response", "not scroll to last position");
    }
    //rv.smoothScrollToPosition(sectionAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
}

private void control_scroll(){
    rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) {
                scroll_usuario = true;
            } else if (dy < 0) {
                scroll_usuario = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a `FloatingActionButton` to your layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more"          // put here your desired icon
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"       // if inside a ConstraintLayout
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" // if inside a ConstraintLayout
/>
```

Then, in your `onCreate`

Assuming `rv = recyclerview`, `layoutmanager = LinearLayoutManager`

```
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutManager.scrollToPosition(yourlist.size() - 1);
        }
    });

   rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() < yourlist.size() - 1) {
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else
                fab.setVisibility(GONE);
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }
    });
```

Then, when a new item arrives,

```
if (fab.getVisibility == View.GONE)    
    layoutmanager.scrollToPosition(yourlist.size() - 1);
```

Because I've no access to your code I use `yourlist.size()` but I think you can use `sectionAdapter.getItemCount()` if you prefer.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: @Dimoreno. Glad to help. Instead of using `fab.setVisibility(...)` you can use `fab.show()` and `fab.hide()`. This way fab appears and disappears with animation like Whatsapp...

Comment: I have a new question can you help me?

Comment: @Dimoreno Sure, what do you need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692194/error-notifydatasetchanged-in-recyclerview-when-its-scroll-to-last-position . that is my problem